# What is parent.right (for example) exactly in QML and how does it differ from parent.anchors.right?

Tags: qt, layout, qml

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/anchor-layout.html tells that parent's `anchors.right` is "an invisible anchor line" and points to `anchors.right : AnchorLine` property of `Item`,

but `parent.right` and `parent.anchors.right` seem to be different things (and you can't anchor to the latter usually, while anchoring to the former works as expected).

Hint me to the docs anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are anchor lines (`QDeclarativeAnchorLine`), one can even anchor to `parent.anchors.right` (or whatever other item's `anchors.right`), if that anchor is set.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any docs but looking into sources showed that `parent.right` is a constant and `parent.anchors.right` is a place where you could set association.

So they shouldn't be the same. You could think of `parent.right` as a `const int RIGHT=1;` and `parent.anchors.right` as `int rightAnchor;`